# Access data from a reshaped numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the following code to write an array of statistic values into a text file (row wise):

```
data_in = np.loadtxt('input_file.asc')

with open('output_file.txt', 'a+') as outfile:
    values = data_in[:,1]
    min_data = np.min(values)
    max_data = np.max(values)
    avg_data = np.mean(values)
    stats = np.array([min_data, max_data, avg_data])
    np.savetxt(outfile, stats.reshape(1,stats.shape[0]), delimiter=' ', newline='\n')
```

I want to use this code to read multiple `data_in` files and append the statistics into a new row of `'output_file.txt'`. I'm using the `reshape` function as suggested in a previous post here, so every batch of statistics is stored in a new row.

My problem is when I want to access the data stored in `'output_file.txt'` for later plotting. If I use:

```
stats_out = np.loadtxt('output_file.txt') 
min_values = stats_out[:,0]
max_values = stats_out[:,1] 
avg_values = stats_out[:,2]
```

I get the Error message: `IndexError: too many indices`

Is this error caused because I'm using the reshape function?

An example of `output_file.txt` after running the script several times is:

```
0.077 -0.330 0.303
0.107 -0.506 0.350
0.092 -0.548 0.405
0.138 -2.358 0.445
0.100 -0.461 0.337
```

An example of `input_file.asc`:

```
-1492.292540 -87.984545   95.515548       NaN    NaN  8.18
-1491.349103 -87.982864   93.908249       NaN    NaN 10.55
-1490.405666 -87.979607   92.304869       NaN    NaN 10.73
-1489.462227 -87.974784   90.707865       NaN  7.740 10.60
-1488.518791 -87.968404   89.119650       NaN    NaN 10.18
-1487.575353 -87.960482   87.542539       NaN    NaN 10.10
-1486.631915 -87.951037   85.978759       NaN    NaN 10.11
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. At the moment I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not too sure how traceback works, sorry. I've added an example of my input_file.asc to the question

Comment: Traceback is the full output of your programm code after the error arises.

Comment: After running the script I'm still not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `min_values = stats_out[:,0]`
`IndexError: too many indices`                                       I'm running Python2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1

Comment: Can you output `stats_out` after reading the input file and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your output file has only one line. So with `stats_out = np.loadtxt('output_file.txt')` you will only get a onedimensional array.
If you then call `stats_out[:,0]` you will get an IndexError.

To solve this problem, you should check the number of dimensions of your data, for example:

```
stats_out = np.loadtxt('output_file.txt')
if stats_out.ndim > 1:
    min_values = stats_out[:,0]
    max_values = stats_out[:,1] 
    avg_values = stats_out[:,2]
else:
    min_values = stats_out[0]
    max_values = stats_out[1] 
    avg_values = stats_out[2]
```